# Search Boolean in List Multidimensional C # and assign value

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, find, multiple-columns

I have a question and do not find how to get the best way to iterate without assigning a value "True" or "False" in a list Multidimensional (2 columns). In other words, if all are "TRUE" assign "FALSE".

I have a way to do one-dimensional lists (1 column) to Find, Contains, Loop, among others. But with 2 columns, I do not find the way.

For now, only a bit literal and extensively that I maintain is this:

My Class:

```
public class LIndexElements
    {
        private Int32 index;
        private Boolean isReady;

        public Int32 Index
        {
            get { return index; }
            set { index = value; }
        }

        public Boolean IsReady
        {
            get { return isReady; }
            set { isReady = value; }
        }
    }
```

My set in the list in and with both columns. Begins validation:

```
for (int i = 0; i <LIndexControls.Count i++) 
{
    if (LIndexControls[i].IsReady) 
    {
       LIndexControls[i].IsReady = false; 
    } 
}
```

It's work! But I'm convinced that most certainly should be a more subtle and optimal method.

Grateful for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't see anything here that is "multi-dimensional".

Comment: When I refer multidimensional, are 2 columns per record. That is, A and B = Record 1. 

Grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand but maybe you can use linq in the case of a list like that?

For exemple :

```
List<LIndexElements> LIndexControls=new List<LIndexElements>();
// Populate your list....
// ...
// ...
// And then :
foreach (LIndexElements elt in LIndexControls.Where((child)=>child.IsReady==True))
{
    elt.IsReady=False;
}
```

Comment: Go! Shorter, and using generic functions themselves. 

Thanked friend. Sorry I can not vote for you for not having the required reputation. 

Get a hug. 

Best regards.